# i cant populate the route (mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am working on a profile route that gets all the registered profiles from database.
.I only want to populate "name" and "avatar" fields from User model.
.populate('model',['name','avatar']) not working .

**Route I want to populate:**

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const profiles = await Profile.find().populate("User", ["name", "avatar"]);
    res.send(profiles);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error !");
  }
});
```

**User Model**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  avatar: {
    type: String,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

**Profile Model**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
let requiredString = { type: String, required: true };
const ProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
  githubusername: String,
  status: requiredString,
  skills: [requiredString],
  experience: [
    {
      title: requiredString,
      company: requiredString,
      location: String,
      from: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
      },
      to: Date,
      current: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
      },
      description: String,
    },
  ],

  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = Profile = mongoose.model("Profile", ProfileSchema);
```

**Output isn't populated with name and avatar** !

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try by doing as follow.

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const profiles = await Profile.find().populate({path:"User",select: {'name', 'avatar'} });
    res.send(profiles);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    res.status(500).send("Server Error !");
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't know how but changing my ref to lower case string worked !!